# flip image using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a image or text and a canvas element in a div .Intially the image or text will be dispayed on clicking the canvas has to be created and displayed in css flip image format

given below is the code which i am using to try and rotate the text with canvas using css3 
but i couldn't make out the mistake

Any kind of input will be helpful thank you
http://jsfiddle.net/tLpemc1k/
html:
    
        this is the text

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>


</div>
```

css:

```
 <style type="text/css">
    .rotator canvas{
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s, z-index 0s 0.25s;
        -webkit

-transform: rotateY(0deg); 
    z-index

:100;
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
    }
    .rotator .clientimg{
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);   
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s, z-index 0s 0.25s;
        z-index: 50;
    }
    .clientimg,canvas
    {
     -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s , z-index 0s 0.25s;
          -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
       -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
        -ms-backface-visibility:hidden;
         -o-backface-visibility:hidden;
            backface-visibility:hidden;
    }
.clientimg
{
   z-index: 100;   
   -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
canvas
{
   z-index: 50;   
   -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);

}
</style>
```

javascript:

```
 var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);

    $(".main").click(function(element){
    $(".main").addClass('rotator');
    });
```

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tLpemc1k/1/) what you are looking for?

Comment: @Harry i want the canvas to be created and displayed on click.Is it possible

Comment: There are some glaring errors in your JSFiddle setup. For example, you omitted using the jQuery library. Also, you have not stated what the intended code is supposed to accomplish. Please add some commenting to your fiddle or here and let us know what it is exactly you expect to see.

Comment: Do you mean like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tLpemc1k/5/). But as pointed out the in the above comment, I did link the jQuery lib in the fiddle.

Comment: @harry but why have u kept backface-visibility :visible.I don't want the backface to visible.the text has to replaced by the canvas ..It has to be something like there is a div in which in the front u are placing an element and on the back some canvas and we are rotating the div such that first text will be visible and then we will rotate and canvas has to be visible

Comment: Ok, if you don't want it then your original fiddle itself work provided you link the jQuery lib and also remove the `<style>` tags from the CSS part because basically thats all that I did.

Comment: ya sorry such a silly mistake..thank u for helping me out

Comment: No problems. I am voting to close the question because it is only a trivial error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean? Flipper element, which flips and shows back and then flips and shows the front:

http://jsfiddle.net/tLpemc1k/7/

Sample taken from [here](http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip)

This code will keep flipping the canvas and the text:

```
$(".main").click(function(element){
    $(".main").toggleClass('rotator');
});
```